# New User not showing via Ajax in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I was trying to work through Section 5 of Working with JavaScript in Rails http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html .

Issue I have is that the new user isn't displayed in the show page until a refresh the entire page. I think I've replicated all the code correctly, but can't see what's wrong.

**users_controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end
...
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.js
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**user/index.html.erb**

```
<b>Users</b>

<ul id="users">
<%= render @users %>
</ul>

<br>

<%= form_with(model: @user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**user/create.js.erb**

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");
```

**logs**

```
started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 17:23:36 +0100
Processing by UsersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xMBe+h9zi5rWE8JXltYw1fGwQUP8AL2iWaaaGVqwbPvYavJgv7eQ0J5hwRL9xkb2S0pnose3X6oo+YXywvlcaQ==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Dave"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Dave"], ["created_at", "2018-03-30 16:23:36.474360"], ["updated_at", "2018-03-30 16:23:36.474360"]]
   (6.3ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering users/create.js.erb
  Rendered users/_user.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered users/create.js.erb (3.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 13.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-30 17:23:38 +0100
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  Rendering users/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Rendered collection of users/_user.html.erb [3 times] (0.4ms)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 49.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

Comment: Have you created the ,js? (app/views/users/create.js)

Comment: @Pablo yes, forgot to include it in post.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console log to look for javascript errors?

Comment: ah, looks like I don't have jquery properly installed `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: then issue might be with Jquery, include this `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` into your application.hrml.erb file, and check if it works. or use gem `jquery-rails`

Comment: Yes you need jquery